# How to save a number from a text file in python?

Tags: regular-expression, python, split

I have a text file, from which I have to extract a number, which is in the line called "width:"
It is like:
width:                  3432

Now I am trying:

```
        import re
        file = open('abc.txt', 'r')
        lines = file.readlines()
        WIDTH=lines[10]
        numbers = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", WIDTH)
        print(numbers)
```

It gives back ['3432']. How can I save it as an int variable in python, to get 3432?

Answer (score 1):

try `awk` & `tr`

```
awk -F"[][]" '{print $2}' file
```

or

`grep`

```
grep -Po "(?<=\[).[0-9].*?(?=\])" file
```

or

in `python`

```
#!/bin/python    
import re

str = open('file.txt', 'r').read()    
m = re.search(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]", str)
print m.group(1)
```

Comment: sorry, i edited my question, cause I am working now with python

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regexes for this, based on your description of what you are trying to do. You can just use Python's `str.startswith` to filter lines you don't care about, and then the `str.split` method to get the part of it you are interested in, passing the value to the `int()` constructor, to cast the string to an integer:

```
for line in open('abc.txt').readlines():
    if line.startswith('width:'):
        number = int(line.split()[-1])

print(number)
```